# DOM todo list when nesting with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm making a todolist right now and encountered a problem when deleting a list.

```
// nest icon inside button tag
delBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';
```

I have nested an icon inside a button tag so when I'm clicking the delete button on the very edge it deletes the ul tag. And when clicking inside of the button tag it deletes a list what I'm exactly aiming to.

So.. How do I have to fix this problem to delete only the one that I want? Whenever I click the edge of the button it's deleting the whole list.

```
  function addTodo(todo) {
    let todoText = todoInput.value; // new input
    if (todo) {
        // existing todo loaded from LS
        todoText = todo.text;
    }

    if (todoText) {
        const todoLI = document.createElement('li');
        const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
        const text = document.createElement('span');
        // nest icon inside button tag
        delBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';

        // DELETE: event
        delBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();

            updateLS();
        });

        text.innerText = todoText;

        todoLI.appendChild(delBtn);
        todoLI.appendChild(text);

        todoUL.appendChild(todoLI);
        todoInput.value = '';

        updateLS();
    }
```

Comment: Please check if you are deleting `parentNode.parentNode` instead of `parentNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) points to the deepest element in the DOM that received the event (*`click` here*). So if you click on the `i` it points to that, but if you click in the button, but outside of `i`, it will point to the `button` element.

So the `.parentNode.parentNode` will be different, depending where you click.

Use [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `target` which points to the element with the event handler so you have a normalized starting point (*the `button` in this case*).

```
delBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();
        updateLS();
    });
```

another approach, since you already have a reference to the `li` item to remove, just use that

```
delBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    todoLI.remove();
    updateLS();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to delegate for the button

I use the closest button to allow clicking on the icon inside the button.
Then I use closest LI to always get to the containing LI

I did not handle the update or storing of the list

```js
const updateLS = () => {}

function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop form

  let todoText = todoInput.value; // new input
  // existing todo loaded from LS
  // const todo = getTodo() || []; // get from localStorage
  const todo = [];

  if (todoText) {
    const todoLI = document.createElement('li');
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    const text = document.createElement('span');
    // nest icon inside button tag
    delBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>';

    text.innerText = todoText;
    todoLI.appendChild(delBtn);
    todoLI.appendChild(text);

    todoUL.appendChild(todoLI);
    todoInput.value = '';

    updateLS();
  }
}

const form = document.getElementById("todoForm");
form.addEventListener("submit",addTodo)
form.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); // make sure we access the button
  if (tgt) {
    tgt.closest("li").remove(); // the container LI
    updateLS();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"  />

<form id="todoForm">
  <input type="text" id="todoInput" autocomplete="off" />

  <ul id="todoUL"></ul>
</form>
```